# Objective C, How to make keaboard to not pop up on UITextView

Tags: objective-c

I have UITextView and I want to use scroll bar when text is longer then the height of the UITextview. Also I don't want users to change the content of the text view. If I uncheck the user interaction check box then users won't be able to change the content but scroll bar won't show up as well. So how I can just make the UITextView to have scroll bar but not to have user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`editable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/editable) property of UITextView will let you disable editing, and so also the keyboard.

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UITextView` Delegate.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>{

}

@end
```

Then, put this in your .m:

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    return NO;
}
```